# Centering position:absolute div within parent position:relative div

Tags: html, css, positioning, css-position

Re: http://jsfiddle.net/WdGdd/3/

Is it possible to center a position:absolute div in its parent position:relative div?

The idea is to make a button whose text is one of two values. Its width stays the length of the whichever value is longer. When the shorter of the two values is being displayed, the text is centered in the button. I don't want to specify any widths in px.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couldn't you change the CSS of #op2 to:

```
#op2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/WdGdd/5/)**.